# How to use workbook activate application class event with automation

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-interop

I need workbook activate application class event code which minimizes "Workbook Window" whenever Workbook is activated.

So, whenever `C:\Book1.xlsx` is activated then minimize "Workbook Window".

Following code just for test begining;

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1

Public WithEvents wb1 As Excel.Workbook

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    xlApp.Visible = True

    Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)

    Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
    wb1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xlsx")

    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000000)
End Sub

End Class
```

Following link may support you;

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/822750/how-to-handle-events-for-excel-by-using-visual-basic-.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do is move the declaration of `xlApp` to class level and declare `WithEvents`:

```
Private WithEvents xlApp As New Excel.Application
```

Now we can make use of the events that come with `Excel.Application`, specifically [WindowActivate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840441.aspx):

> Occurs when any workbook window is activated.

```
Private Sub xlApp_WindowActivate(Wb As Excel.Workbook, Wn As Excel.Window) Handles xlApp.WindowActivate
    xlApp.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMinimized
End Sub
```

And [WindowResize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822648.aspx):

> Occurs when any workbook window is resized.

```
Private Sub xlApp_WindowResize(Wb As Excel.Workbook, Wn As Excel.Window) Handles xlApp.WindowResize
    xlApp.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMinimized
End Sub
```

As you can see, within these handlers, I am setting the `WindowState` property to `xlMinimized`. This means that whenever I try and bring up the `Workbook` it becomes minimised again.

In full your code would look something similar to this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents xlApp As New Excel.Application

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        xlApp.Visible = True

        Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
        wb1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xlsx")

    End Sub

    Private Sub xlApp_WindowActivate(Wb As Excel.Workbook, Wn As Excel.Window) Handles xlApp.WindowActivate
        xlApp.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMinimized
    End Sub

    Private Sub xlApp_WindowResize(Wb As Excel.Workbook, Wn As Excel.Window) Handles xlApp.WindowResize
        xlApp.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMinimized
    End Sub

End Class
```